# Can I transition the flex-grow of a flex box to produce an animation?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, css-animations

Is it possible to transition the items in an flexbox?
When you click I want all items to collapse except the one that is clicked.
The one that is clicked should use all available space from the container.

```js
// only works once!
$(".item").click(function() {
  $(".item").not(this).each(function() {
    $(this).addClass("collapse");
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
.item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  transition: all 2s;
}
.collapse {
  flex-grow: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" style="background: red">a</div>
  <div class="item" style="background: green">b</div>
  <div class="item" style="background: blue">c</div>
  <div class="item" style="background: purple">d</div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/clankill3r/L8hktsgn/

Comment: You cannot transition `flex-grow` from/to 0. http://oli.jp/2010/css-animatable-properties/

Comment: Could anyone tell me why jQuery's animate method doesn't work in this case?

Comment: This post didn't age well... It is now possible on Chrome 114 to animate to/from `flex-grow: 0`.

Answer (score 47):

`flex-grow` [*is* animatable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties) but only if the value is a [`<number>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/number#Interpolation). However it seems that Google Chrome (v41) doesn't trigger the animation if the value is set to `0`.

A workaround for this could be to use a very small value instead — something like `0.0001`:

**[Updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/L8hktsgn/13/)**.

```js
$(".item").click(function() {
    $(".item").addClass("collapse");
    $(this).removeClass("collapse");    
});
```

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;    
}

.container {
    flex-basis: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}

.item {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: auto;
    transition: all 2s;
}

.collapse {
    flex-grow: 0.001;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="item" style="background: red">a</div>
    <div class="item" style="background: green">b</div>
    <div class="item" style="background: blue">c</div>
    <div class="item" style="background: purple">d</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it just my impression, or is the `transition-timing-function` ignored when transitioning `flex-grow` (I can't really tell a difference between the easings)?

Comment: @nils It seems to be working (tested in Chrome 46). Can be verified by playing with cubic bezier editor in dev tools, for instance: `cubic-bezier(0.19, 1.41, 0.54, -0.43)` as timing function.

Comment: and what if we can't use flex-grow, because our container has not a defined height? My usecase is that I want to build a toast system (user feedback system) where 3 toasts can be displayed at the same time. When first toast disappear, the 2nd one should position itself to the former position of the first toast with an animation. Any idea?

Comment: Good catch on the 0.0001, one of the usual nasty monkey patches we have to write.

Comment: Just found out that this will break on IE11. So you probably shouldn't use it, unless you're okay with excluding IE users.

Comment: @WilfredSpringer Please define "break on IE11". `flex-grow` is supposed to be animatable according to the spec; If IE11 doesn't implement that, this is its fault, not the spec nor the answer.

Comment: @HashemQolami I am writing software that is actually used. I am saying that if you apply this trick, your page *won't even load* in IE11. It will just show you a blank page. And it's not about animation: it's about not supporting values for `flex-grow` < 1.

Comment: @WilfredSpringer Could you please provide a minimal online example? Perhaps I can help. I checked the current demo out on IE11, the layout looked as expected but the animation didn't. I also tried `flex-grow`>1 but no luck. Seems IE11 doesn't support animating that property.

Comment: If anyone is interested, here's a pure javascript version: http://jsfiddle.net/4bth1cLn/3/

Answer (score 5):

```
$(".item").click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('collapse');
    $(".item").not(this).each(function() {
        $(this).addClass("collapse");    
    });


});
```

and you can animate flex-grow from 20 to 1

```
.item {
    flex-grow: 20;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.collapse {
    flex-grow: 1;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L8hktsgn/11/

Comment: I added jsfiddle with animate

Answer (score 2):

If you want only one row this could work https://codepen.io/balvin/pen/gKrXdM but if you want to wrap them you could use https://codepen.io/balvin/pen/wXGyYw 
Seems that it's a hack, but setting `width:0;flex-grow:1` it's the solution, but in order to wrap the elements, you need to explicity tell `width` to the browser, because it does not know at which width you want the elemements to wrap, and with that in mind you just play with setTimeout. Check the codes

Answer (score 1):

You can work with `max-height`.

```
.item
{
  max-height:100%;
}

.collapse
{
  max-height: 64px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L8hktsgn/9/