# Transitioning flex-basis from auto

Tags: css, flexbox

Is there a trick to transitioning `flex-basis` from `auto` to other values? From what I gather this is the one exception to the rule... which is annoying because it's arguably the most useful.

Here's an example:
http://codepen.io/jamiewinder/pen/WrgrEB

Clicking the 'Toggle' button should open the drawer using a transition. The opacity works, but the height - defined using `flex-basis` - does not. It works if I set `flex-basis` to a number of pixels, or a percentage, or anything other than `auto` which means I need to know the height of the content in order to get this working.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transition flex-grow of items in a flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29625037/transition-flex-grow-of-items-in-a-flexbox)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`flex-basis` can be animated and transitioned ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis)). However, like other properties, it can only be done if you set the values to actual length values (like `px`, `%`, etc. and `calc()`). More info can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css?rq=1) question.

Comment: That's a shame if so. I'm using this in a flexbox scenario but I'm not sure your last link applies to this (I've had cross-browser issues with mixing max-height and flexboxes before). Thanks.

Comment: @Barguast Not trying to get you to use `max-height` for your issue. Just pointing to it, since it's basically the same issue: not being able to transition `auto` values.