# React onClick add class to clicked element but remove from the others

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

so what i try to achieve here is very similar to what is done here [Transition flex-grow of items in a flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29625037/transition-flex-grow-of-items-in-a-flexbox)

But what i wonder how this could be done with React say i have this code

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        classNameToUse: ''
    };

    this.onElementClicked = this.onElementClicked.bind(this);
}

onElementClicked() {
    this.setState({ classNameToUse : 'big-size'})
}

render() {

    return (
        <div>
            <div className={this.state.classNameToUse} onClick={this.onElementClicked} >
              something
            </div>
            <div className={this.state.classNameToUse onClick={this.onElementClicked} >
               something else
            </div>
        </div>
       );
    }
}
```

This would of course add the className to them both but what i want to achieve is that one of them grows big with animation and the other collapse. And it sohuldnt matter if i have 2 or 10 elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set active index on click:

```
// State
this.state = {
  activeIndex: null
};
// event
onElementClicked(e) {
  this.setState({ activeIndex: e.target.index })
}
// class to use
className={this.index === this.state.activeIndex ? 'big-size' : ''}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [divs,] = useState(['blue', 'green', 'black']);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);
  
  const onClick = (id) => {
    setSelected(id);
  }
  
  return <div className="container">
    {divs.map(pr => <div key={pr} style={{background: pr}} className={`box ${pr === selected ? 'selected' : ''}`} onClick={() => onClick(pr)}></div>)}
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
}

.box {
  flex: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
}

.selected {
  flex: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/material-ui-lab-umd@4.0.0-alpha.32/material-ui-lab.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```