# Trying to target each image on hover not all at once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to hover over each image and have different content(an image or text for this example) show for each image.

Right now when I hover over a image it changes to all of them. I know i have to use an event but not sure on how to use it using hooks.

```
const Logos = () => {
const [defaultImg, setNewImg] = useState("image1");

const onMouseLeave = (e) => {
console.log(e.target, "img leave");

setNewImg("image1");
};

const onMouseEnter = (e) => {
console.log(e.target, "enter");

setNewImg("image2");
};

return (
<div className="images">
  <div className="logos-container">
    <h3 className="title">Trinity title goes here</h3>
    <div className="logos">
      {logos.map((logo) => (
        <Link to="/">
          <img
            key={logo.image}
            src={defaultImg}
            alt=""
            className="logo"
            onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}
            onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}
          />
        </Link>
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
);
};
```

Comment: What does BreezeLogo do?

Comment: Add the event listener inside `useEffect` hook and also remove it inside of it. More on useEffect usage https://danburzo.github.io/react-recipes/recipes/use-effect.html

Comment: @Asutosh, sorry thats an img I imported. I'll change it real quick

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62309727/2138752

Comment: The issue is with src={defaultImg} , as on one image mouse hover you are changing the state, the whole component gets rerenderd and all Link refering to the above defaultImg changes.

Comment: @Mu-Majid, what exactly would I put inside the useEffect hook? The onMouseLeave and Enter functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are changing the state for every images since you pass the same `defaultImg` to each image.

You should probably put this logic in an `Image` component that handles its own state.

```
const Image = ({ logo }) => {
  const [defaultImg, setImg] = useState(BreezeLogo);

  const onMouseLeave = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target, "img leave");

    setImg(BreezeLogo);
  };

  const onMouseEnter = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target, "enter");

    setImg(SafebridgeLogo);
  };

  return (
    <img
      key={logo.image}
      src={defaultImg}
      alt=""
      className="logo"
      onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}
      onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}
    />
  );
};

const Logos = ({ logos }) => {
  return (
    <div className="images">
      <div className="logos-container">
        <h3 className="title">Trinity title goes here</h3>
        <div className="logos">
          {logos.map((logo) => (
            <Link to="/">
              <Image logo={logo} />
            </Link>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Ahh I see, That worked since each image changes now instead of all of them at once, Thanks!