# Div Container inside another Div with 'max-width' breaks out

Tags: html, css

The website should have a maximum `width` of `1300px` and three columns: left, content and right.
All columns should be individually scrollable.
The left and right columns should disappear to the outside after the button is pressed.
Most of it already works, but I can't find a solution for the following:

- the right column is outside the page (max-width is ignored?)
- All three columns behave differently when they are fade out;
- - right is good, left is too fast and content jumps and does not fade

```css
/* dont display the checkboxes */
#nav_toggle_right,#nav_toggle_left{
  position:absolute; opacity:0; display:none
}

/* more useless space */
ul li{
  line-height: 8;
}

/* left button */
#nav_toggle_left~label.nav_toggle_left {
  position:fixed; 
  display:block; 
  cursor:pointer; 
  text-align:center; 
  z-index:300; 
  font-size:28px; 
  width:40px; 
  height:40px; 
  top:9px; 
  left:20px; 
  line-height:40px;
}

#nav_toggle_left~label .lable_before {
  display:block; 
  color:#000000; 
  background-color:#FFFFFF; 
  border:1px solid #000000; 
  border-radius:10px;
}

#nav_toggle_left~label .lable_after {
  display:none;
}

#nav_toggle_left:checked~label .lable_before{
  display:none;
}

#nav_toggle_left:checked~label .lable_after {
  display:block; 
  color:#000000; 
  background-color:#FFFFFF; 
  border:1px solid #000000; 
  border-radius:10px;
}

#nav_toggle_left:checked~.menu_left {
  -webkit-transform:translateX(-100vw); 
  transform:translateX(-100vw)
}

/* right button */
#nav_toggle_right~label.nav_toggle_right {
  position:fixed; 
  display:block; 
  cursor:pointer; 
  text-align:center; 
  z-index:300; 
  font-size:28px; 
  width:40px; 
  height:40px; 
  top:9px; 
  right:20px; 
  line-height:40px;
}

#nav_toggle_right~label .lable_before {
  display:block; 
  color:#000000; 
  background-color:#FFFFFF; 
  border:1px #000000); 
  border-radius:10px;
}

#nav_toggle_right~label .lable_after {
  display:none;
}

#nav_toggle_right:checked~label .lable_before{
  display:none;
}

#nav_toggle_right:checked~label .lable_after {
  display:block; 
  color:#000000; 
  background-color:#FFFFFF; 
  border:1px #000000);
  border-radius:10px;
}

#nav_toggle_right:checked~.menu_right {
  -webkit-transform:translateX(290px); 
  transform:translateX(290px)
}

/* widht of page */
.page{
  max-width:1050px;
}

/* left menu */
.menu_left{
  height:100%; 
  width:250px; 
  background-color:#f5f5f5; 
  border-right:solid 1px #c9c9c9; 
  inline-height:20px;
  overflow-y:scroll; 
  overflow-x:hidden; 
  scrollbar-width:none; 
  left:0px; 
  top:0px; 
  position:fixed; 
}

/* right menu */
.menu_right{
  height:100%; 
  width:250px; 
  background-color:#e3e3e3; 
  border-left:solid 1px #c9c9c9; 
  overflow-y:scroll; 
  overflow-x:hidden; 
  scrollbar-width:none; 
  right:0px; 
  top:0px; 
  position:fixed;
}

/* content */
.content{
  height:1000vh; 
  min-width:300px; 
  background-color:#FCFCFC; 
  scrollbar-width:none; 
  overflow-y:scroll; 
  overflow-x:hidden; 
  scrollbar-width:none; 
  margin-left:250px; 
  margin-right:250px; 
  padding:20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

/* content without menu(s) */
#nav_toggle_left:checked~.content{
  margin-left:0px!important;
}

#nav_toggle_right:checked~.content{
  margin-right:0px!important;
}

/* same transition for both menues */
.transition{    
  -webkit-transition:1.53s transform;
  transition:1.53s transform;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.38,.52,.37,1); 
  transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.38,.52,.37,1);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="page">
    <input type="checkbox" id="nav_toggle_left">
    <label class="nav_toggle_left" for="nav_toggle_left">
        <span class="lable_after">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="lable_before">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
        </span>
    </label>

    <div class="menu_left transition">
        <ul>
            <li>Menu left</li>
            <li>Menu left</li>
            <li>Menu left</li>
            <li>Menu left</li>
            <li>Menu left</li>
            <li>Menu left</li>
            <li>Menu left</li>
            <li>Menu left</li>
        </ul>     
    </div>

    <input type="checkbox" id="nav_toggle_right">
    <label class="nav_toggle_right" for="nav_toggle_right">
        <span class="lable_after">
            <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="lable_before">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i> 
        </span>
    </label>
    <div class="menu_right transition">
        <ul>
            <li>Menu right</li>
            <li>Menu right</li>
            <li>Menu right</li>
            <li>Menu right</li>
            <li>Menu right</li>
            <li>Menu right</li>
            <li>Menu right</li>
            <li>Menu right</li>
        </ul>  
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <i class="fa fa-list"></i> 
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        
        If you were a member of the Bloods and became paralyzed do you then become a member of the Crips?. If you were a member of the Bloods and became paralyzed do you then become a member of the Crips?. Smiling could easily be misinterpreted for showing your teeth to someone because they said something that made you happy. Twitter is the rice of social media. Smiling could easily be misinterpreted for showing your teeth to someone because they said something that made you happy. A tagline for a special highway that is easy to navigate while under the influence of drugs: Take the High Road. Why don't we call glasses duocles. North America should be called Russia since people are always moving so fast. Gralitica. We need more werkin and less twerkin if you ask me. Balooby. I started a sensory deprivation chamber business - it involves really dark curtains, ear plugs, and a sleeping mask. To Catch A Predator would have been a great name for a Steve Irwin show. Mintslavicia. North America should be called Russia since people are always moving so fast. Gralitica. Most streets are two-way streets...why does that make love so special?. Thank you for using my words in your work. Twitter is the rice of social media.
    </div>

</div>
```

Or a [codepen](https://codepen.io/koljal/pen/pogXqQw)

Comment: Please make a minimal demo, you can "cut" away about 80% of the code in this question because it's not relevant

Comment: There is no code cutted away, there are no links and no content yet, but i will first make the technical stuff and then add the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use flex-grow/flex-shrink.
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-shrink/
You can get a consistent transition using it.
Some examples given on this Question/Answers
[Transition flex-grow of items in a flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29625037/transition-flex-grow-of-items-in-a-flexbox)