# CSS simultaneous transition on multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

So, I have 3 flexbox containers of the same dimension. When I click on one of them, it should stretch to become bigger then the others, and then back to normal if I click on it again.
I've made it using JS, and it works.
The problem is that when I already have one the boxes stretched and I try to stretch another one, the transition duration increases. And I can't figure out why. I thought the different transitions would start simultaneously.

This is the code:

```
/* HTML */

<div class="flexbox">
            <div class="box-1" onclick="box1();">
                <h3>Box 1</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore</p>
            </div>
            <div class="box-2" onclick="box2();">
                <h3>Box 2</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore</p>
            </div>
            <div class="box-3" onclick="box3();">
                <h3>Box 3</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

```
/* CSS */

.flexbox {
    display: flex;
    width: auto;
    justify-content: center;
}

.flexbox div {
    border: 1px #ccc solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 2px 10px;
    transition: flex-grow 1s linear 0s;
}

.box-1{
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.box-2 {
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.box-3 {
  flex-grow: 0;
}
```

```
/* JS */

function box1(){
  const box1 = document.getElementsByClassName('box-1')[0];
  if(box1.style.flexGrow != '4'){
      box1.style.flexGrow = '4';
  } else {
    box1.style.flexGrow = '0';
  }

  const box2 = document.getElementsByClassName('box-2')[0];
  box2.style.flexGrow = '0';

  const box3 = document.getElementsByClassName('box-3')[0];
  box3.style.flexGrow = '0';
}

function box2(){
  const box2 = document.getElementsByClassName('box-2')[0];
  if(box2.style.flexGrow != '4'){
      box2.style.flexGrow = '4';
  } else {
    box2.style.flexGrow = '0';
  }

  const box1 = document.getElementsByClassName('box-1')[0];
  box1.style.flexGrow = '0';

  const box3 = document.getElementsByClassName('box-3')[0];
  box3.style.flexGrow = '0';
}

function box3(){
  const box3 = document.getElementsByClassName('box-3')[0];
  if(box3.style.flexGrow != '4'){
      box3.style.flexGrow = '4';
  } else {
    box3.style.flexGrow = '0';
  }

  const box1 = document.getElementsByClassName('box-1')[0];
  box1.style.flexGrow = '0';

  const box2 = document.getElementsByClassName('box-2')[0];
  box2.style.flexGrow = '0';
}
```

How can I have the transition duration to be always the same (1s in this example)?

Comment: FYI when you seem to copy and paste code and change a few things, that is usually a hint you should try to figure out a way to make a function so you can reuse it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of improvements that can be made to your code that will reduce duplication, avoid complications of interacting with the live [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) that `getElementsByClassName` returns, allow you to avoid using inline `onclick` assignments, and will cause the transition to only take 1 second.

The example below implements a single `grow()` function which is called by listeners attached to each box. The listeners are added by iterating over the [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) returned by querying the DOM with `.querySelectorAll('.box')` and calling `addEventListener()` on each element.

In the CSS we declare classes for each state we want our boxes to be able to have - in this case `flex-grow: 0` and `flex-grow:4`. Then in our `grow()` function we simply add or remove these styles as necessary based on which box was clicked.

```js
function grow(e){
      // if the clicked box already has class 'flexgrow4' return
      if (e.currentTarget.classList.contains('flexgrow4')) return;
      
      // otherwise find the element in the flexbox container that has
      // class 'flexgrow4' and replace it with 'flexgrow0'
      const lastActive = flexbox.querySelector('.flexgrow4');
      if (lastActive) lastActive.classList.replace('flexgrow4', 'flexgrow0');
      
      // finally, replace 'flexgrow0' with 'flexgrow4' on the clicked box
      e.currentTarget.classList.replace('flexgrow0', 'flexgrow4');
}

const flexbox = document.querySelector('.flexbox');
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box')

boxes.forEach(box => box.addEventListener("click", grow, false));
```

```css
.flexbox {
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    justify-content: center;
}

.flexbox div {
    border: 1px #ccc solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 250px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 2px 10px;
    transition: all 1s linear 0s;
}

.flexgrow0 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.flexgrow4 {
  flex-grow: 4;
  background-color:tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
            <div class="box flexgrow0">
                <h3>Box 1</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore</p>
            </div>
            <div class="box flexgrow0">
                <h3>Box 2</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore</p>
            </div>
            <div class="box flexgrow0">
                <h3>Box 3</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was really useful. I'm really at the beginning so I'm not at ease with this language.

Comment: Ok, I've tried your code, but there are 2 things I don't understand. 
First, where does the code used to add eventListeners run? Cause I've put it on my JS file, but I't doesn't work automatically. How can I make it work? 
And second, I think the duration of the transition is different when I "open" the first box compared to when I have already a box "opened".

Comment: @AndreaMontanari I've looked into the timing issue you mentioned and it is indeed faster on the first opening. There is a related question here: [Transition flex-grow of items in a flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29625037/transition-flex-grow-of-items-in-a-flexbox) which discusses some of the vagaries of transitioning flex-grow but the solutions presented don't directly fix your problem. The timing seems to act correctly as soon as the children fill the width of the parent, so instead of using `flex-grow: 0` as your base state you could use `flex-grow: 1` - snippet edited.

Comment: As for adding the event listeners, you can run it in the global scope after the DOM has finished loading, or wrap it in a function and call it explicitly, but also be sure to add the `box` class and the relevant starting class to each child di